# How can I get all the nodes of a xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, nodes

Let's say I have this XML file:

```
<Names>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
        <LastName>Smith</LastName>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <FirstName>James</FirstName>
        <LastName>White</LastName>
    </Name>
</Names>
```

And now I want to print all the names of the node:

```
Names
Name
FirstName
LastName
```

I managed to get the all in a XmlNodeList, but I dont know how SelectNodes works.

```
XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes(/*What goes here*/);
```

I want to select all nodes, and then do a foreach of xnList (Using the .Value property I assume).

Is this the correct approach? How can I use the selectNodes to select all the nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensuring you have LINQ and LINQ to XML in scope:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
```

If you load them into an `XDocument`:

```
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);    // if from string
var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlFile); // if from file
```

You can do something like:

```
doc.Descendants().Select(n => n.Name).Distinct()
```

This will give you a collection of all distinct `XName`s of elements in the document. If you don't care about XML namespaces, you can change that to:

```
doc.Descendants().Select(n => n.Name.LocalName).Distinct()
```

which will give you a collection of all distinct element names as strings.

Comment: Sorry, 'System.Xml.XmlDocument' does not contain a definition for 'Descendats', should I be Importing somthing that I am not?

Comment: Like I said, you need an `XDocument`, not `XmlDocument` to do this. I think `XDocument` is easier to work with, so I would suggest that you use that instead of `XmlDocument`.

Comment: Ohh sorry, but I get the same error message with XDocument: Error 1 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' does not contain a definition for 'Descendats' and no extension method 'Descendats' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\majo\Desktop\Obligatorio\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 66 17 ExerciseOne

Comment: There was a small spelling error (`Descendants` was spelt `Descendats`). It's fixed now, try again.

Comment: @yamen ahh good catch but it now gives me: Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension method 'Select' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\majo\Desktop\Obligatorio\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 66 31 ExerciseOne Any Ideas why?

Comment: Perhaps also add `using System.Linq` on top of `using System.Xml.Linq` in your namespace imports declaration?. I've updated the answer to show this.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing it.

With XDocument and LINQ-XML

```
foreach(var name in doc.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>().Select(x => x.Name).Distinct()) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(name); 
}
```

If you are using C# 3.0 or above, you can do this

```
var data = XElement.Load("c:/test.xml"); // change this to reflect location of your xml file 
var allElementNames =  
(from e in in data.Descendants() 
select e.Name).Distinct();
```

Comment: Why so verbose? `doc.Root.DescendantNodes().OfType<XElement>()` is the same as `doc.Descendants()` (except the latter could be more efficient). And I'm not sure why are you suggesting two different ways, `XElement` isn't available before .Net 3.5 anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what else I should be importing:` Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XNode>' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XNode>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\majo\Desktop\Obligatorio\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 66 61 ExerciseOne`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 using System.Xml.Linq;
```

Then you can do

```
var element = XElement.Parse({Your xml string});

    Console.Write(element.Descendants("Name").Select(el => string.Format("{0} {1}", el.Element("FirstName").Value, el.Element("LastName").Value)));
```